# Variable is undefined after function returns and requires two clicks to set variable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have one HTML file:

One for a password reset...standard form with enter email, submit and an error div if the function returns an error):

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="reset(f.value)">
     <div class="form-error">
         {{msg}}
     </div>
     <input matInput placeholder="Email" ngModel name="email" id="email" type="email" required>     
     <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!f.valid">Login</button>                 
</form>
```

I deleted some stuff to make it more readable, but yes it works. Here is my forgot email .ts file:

```
userService: UserService //Helper to forgot email function call
msg: string;             //If error messages occur, div will be populated

//Sends the email from the form to the UserService method
reset(email) {
    this.msg = this.userService.reset(email.email);
    console.log(this.msg);
}
```

Here is my UserService function:

```
reset(email):string {
    this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
    .catch(err => {
      this.errorMessage = err.message;
      return this.errorMessage;
    })
}
```

My problem is, when I enter an invalid email, the DIV in the html populates after two clicks. After the first click, the msg is returned undefined, what is keeping my div from populating on the error message on the first click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this block:

```
reset(email):string {
    this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
    .catch(err => {
      this.errorMessage = err.message;
      return this.errorMessage;
    })
}
```

That `return` statement actually goes nowhere. It doesn't make it out of the `reset` method and essentially goes unused.

You *can* return it out of `reset`, but that will take the form of a promise, which means you need a `then` block when you call it:

```
this.userService.reset(email.email).then(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

I'd personally recommend simply letting the rejection bubble up out of `reset` though, leading to:

```
reset(email):string {
    return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
}
```

And then

```
this.userService.reset(email.email)
    .catch(err => {
      this.errorMessage = err.message;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**reset** method in **UserService** should return a string and it's not returning anything. Implement it like this..

```
// UserService

reset(email):string {
   return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
}


// Component
userService: UserService;
msg: string;
reset(email) {
   this.userService.reset(email.email).catch(err => this.msg = err.message);
}
```